# Trying to move an item given by an index to the start of a linked list

Tags: c, list, hyperlink

I am trying to find a string in a linked list based off of its numeric location in the linked list and move it to the start of the list. However instead of moving it to start it gets removed from the list all together. I feel like there's an issue with one of my links and I'm not sure how to correct it.

```
void FindPrintMove(NODE *start, int index) {
    int size = 1;  // index starts at 1 since this is what the program requires
    NODE *cur = start;
    NODE *prev = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (size == index) {
            //printf("%s", cur->word);
            if (prev == NULL) {
                break; //already at start
            } else {
                prev->next = cur->next;
                cur->next = start;
                start = cur;
                break;
            }
        }
        size++;
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the beginning of the list, because you ony get a copy of the head pointer. You should change the prototype to either receive a pointer to the head node:

```
void FindPrintMove(NODE **headp, int index) {
    int size = 1;  // index starts at 1 since this is what the program requires
    NODE *start = *headp;
    NODE *cur = start;
    NODE *prev = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (size == index) {
            //printf("%s", cur->word);
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = cur->next;
                cur->next = start;
                start = cur;
            }
            break;
        }
        size++;
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    *headp = start;
}
```

Or you could return the possibly updated list head:

```
NODE *FindPrintMove(NODE *start, int index) {
    int size = 1;  // index starts at 1 since this is what the program requires
    NODE *cur = start;
    NODE *prev = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if (size == index) {
            //printf("%s", cur->word);
            if (prev != NULL) {
                prev->next = cur->next;
                cur->next = start;
                start = cur;
            }
            break;
        }
        size++;
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

Note that `prev` can be omitted:

```
NODE *FindPrintMove(NODE *start, int index) {
    if (start != NULL && index > 1) {
        NODE *cur = start;
        NODE *next;
        int pos = 2;  // index of the next element
        while ((next = cur->next) != NULL) {
            if (pos == index) {
                cur->next = next->next;
                next->next = start;
                start = next;
                break;
            }
            pos++;
            cur = next;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

Comment: I used the first method and it works very well, the other 2 will have to be something I keep in mind for future uses thanks for the help!

Comment: @YakovFainshetin: you can accept this answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.